# jQuery cannot select children

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-selectors

So I'm using jQuery to select some elements in an angular post-link function. Only problem is, jQuery can't find any children.

```
var tr = tbl.find('> thead > tr');

console.log('th', tr.children('th').length, tr.children().length, tr[0].children);
```

Output:

[image: What I see in the console]

What gives?

EDIT

Here's the HTML essentially

```
<table my-directive>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th sorting-header="foo">foo</th>
      <th sorting-header="foo">foo</th>
      <th sorting-header="foo">foo</th>
      <th sorting-header="foo">foo</th>
      <th sorting-header="foo">foo</th>
      <th sorting-header="foo">foo</th>
      <th sorting-header="foo">foo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
</table>
```

EDIT 2

I think I'm running into some type of race condition. Like I said I didn't write the original directive, I'm just tweaking it. It seems that when I'm handed the `tbl` element the table doesn't have the elements in it yet (so I suppose) because a `tr[0].innerHTML` spits out a bunch of `<!-- ngIf:` clauses but no elements. I guess this is some spooky race condition.

Thanks for all the help everyone, I'm just going to go about this a different way now I guess.

Comment: When is your jQuery code running? The elements might not be created yet. (This is exactly why mixing jQuery and AngularJS should be avoided as much as possible.)

Comment: Then why do they show in the console if I use just javascript?

Comment: Have you read this? There's probably a better way to accomplish your mission without using jQuery selectors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: @isherwood yes, I need to pull the text() of these elements post-link. Technically, I could setup a directive and a service and all that but I'm modifying existing code and don't want to add all that.

Comment: Ok, then show us the HTML that the script is acting on (`tbl`).

Comment: I couldn't recreate your error with the information given. http://jsfiddle.net/j8sLn27o/

Comment: @ClaytonLeis indeed, I can only guess that his tbl variable has been declared incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ty using this code to access:

```
var rows= $('#element_ID > tbody > tr').length
var columns=$('#element_ID').find('tr')[0].cells.length;
var text =  $($('#element_ID').find('tbody > tr')[rows-1]).children('td')[counter].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother everyone, looks like this was a classic race condition.

I decided to barf this to the `console`

`console.log('th', tr.children('th').length, tr.children().length, tr[0].children.length)`

and now I get 3 zeroes. So I guess what I was seeing in the `console` was due to the console watching the nodeList and live updating its changes.

@Blazemonger nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

try using `var tr = tbl.children('thead > tr');`